# Varnish - Could not get hold of varnishd, is it running?

Tags: varnish

Running any of the commands **varnishstat, varnishhist, varnishlog, varnishtop** will give the error message as

```
Could not get hold of varnishd, is it running?
```

Below is some information for understanding.

**sudo service varnish status**

```
varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-11-15 15:28:04 UTC; 1h 16min ago
  Process: 10235 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m (code=ex
 Main PID: 10251 (varnishd)
    Tasks: 217
   Memory: 106.2M
      CPU: 1.673s
   CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service
           ├─10251 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
           └─10271 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m

Nov 15 15:28:03 varnish1 systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Nov 15 15:28:04 varnish1 varnishd[10235]: Debug: Platform: Linux,4.11.0-1014-azure,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Nov 15 15:28:04 varnish1 varnishd[10251]: Platform: Linux,4.11.0-1014-azure,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Nov 15 15:28:04 varnish1 varnishd[10235]: Debug: Child (10271) Started
Nov 15 15:28:04 varnish1 varnishd[10251]: Child (10271) Started
Nov 15 15:28:04 varnish1 varnishd[10251]: Child (10271) said Child starts
Nov 15 15:28:04 varnish1 systemd[1]: Started Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
```

**sudo service varnishd status**

```
varnishd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

**sudo service varnishd start**

```
Failed to start varnishd.service: Unit varnishd.service not found.
```

**varnishd -V**

```
varnishd (varnish-5.2.1 revision 67e562482)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2015 Varnish Software AS
```

**Answer:**

```
sudo varnishstat
sudo varnishhist
sudo varnishlog
sudo varnishtop
```

Comment: fixed it..   i was missing sudo

Answer (score 6):

If you’re using Varnish utilities as unprivileged user, you’re probably missing privileges to execute some actions. For some distros, it’s enough to add yourself to Varnish’s group:

```
gpasswd -a my_user varnish
```

Then put the new group in use and at least varnishstat should work.

Answer (score 1):

If `sudo varnishstat` doesn't help: check if varnish is started

```
sudo /etc/init.d/varnish start
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked fine for me:

sudo varnishadm

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread, however the answers here did not help.
As per: http://lists.varnish-cache.org/pipermail/varnish-misc/2020-July/026914.html when you have updated the serverhostname, you need a full server reboot.